# Why does this powershell snippet produce extra blank lines?

Tags: powershell

This command will produce 1 extra line at the top and 3 more at the bottom.

```
Get-Process | select Name  | ft -HideTableHeaders | Out-File .\process.txt
```

The same thing happens with other lists such as reading a directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same result as in previous answer, but in another syntax:

```
Get-Process | foreach{ $_.Name}  > .\process.txt
```

There still is empty line in the end, though

Comment: Powershell can can be annoying sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn it into a string and trim it:

```
(Get-Process | select Name  | ft -HideTableHeaders | Out-String).Trim() | Out-File .\process.txt
```

Rather than three, there is now only one empty line at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks the empy lines are due to the format-table output and out-file puts line terminators between strings , but I'm not so sure.

To avoid this you can do something like this if you need just the name list in a file:

```
Get-Process |  % { if ( $_ -ne $null ) { $_.name } } | Out-File .\process.txt
```

It will be usefull if `Out-File` had a `-SuppressLastEmptyLine` switch to avoid that last empty
line.